# OBJ vs 3DS - Whats the best format for Android 3D Development

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

whats your prefered file format for 3d models?
OBJ or 3DS format?
I would use this on Android.
Therefore the file size of the models should be small and fast to parse.
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OBJ is much better from my experience. 3DS files have some shortcomings that make it less usable.

```
1) The number of vertices and polygons per mesh is limited to 65536.
2) Accurate vertex normals cannot be stored in the .3ds file.
```

OBJ is very easy to parse, as it is almost already in the correct format for rendering. Just fill a vertex array, a normal array and render. Another option is you can reformat the data into your own data format on a PC so that the device reads the file in faster. To see a more detailed answer, see my post here: [Fastest way to load arrays of vertices and face indices into OpenGL-ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328412/fastest-way-to-load-arrays-of-vertices-and-face-indices-into-opengl-es)

Comment: One problem with obj is it cannot do any 3d animation.